# cts:value-co-occurrences and cts:query option

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to find use the `cts:value-co-occurrences` of a give document property for a given search string,, When I do the regular search I get 546 results back but when I do with cts:value-co-occurrence, I get only 3 documents.. Following is my code

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace prop = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property";
declare namespace meta = "http://ir.abbivenet.com/content-repo/metadata";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"  at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xqy";




let $q := "(TNF)" 

let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="collection">
      <collection prefix=""/>
    </constraint>
    <constraint name="properties">
      <properties />
    </constraint>
    <term>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <return-facets>false</return-facets>
    <return-values>false</return-values>
    <return-constraints>false</return-constraints>
    <return-frequencies>false</return-frequencies>
    <return-qtext>false</return-qtext>
    <search-option>unfaceted</search-option>
    <search-option>score-simple</search-option>
  </options>

let $start := 1
let $page-length :=1000000

let $query-original := cts:query(search:parse($q, $options))


let $m := cts:value-co-occurrences(
              cts:element-reference(xs:QName('meta:id')),
              cts:uri-reference(),
              ('map','properties'), $query-original)
return $m
```

This returns only 3 results.. but if I do the following I get 546 results

```
let $result := search:search($q, $options, $start, $page-length) 
return $result
```

All the documents have the property `<id>` , so I do not understand why the difference.. I understand I am using `map` , so will return or should return unique `<id>` keys.. if that is the case I should get 241 results not 3.

Comment: Is it possible that you have fragment roots configured? If there were many fragment roots per document, then search would return snippets for and a count of unique fragments while, because you're using `cts:uri-reference`, `cts:value-co-occurrences` would only return unique document URIs.

Comment: For sanity sake, maybe dump out the index: xs:QName('meta:id') using cts:values and make sure it has what you expect in there (241 values)

Comment: when I do this `let $m := cts:values((cts:element-reference(xs:QName('meta:id'))),(),
              ('map','properties'), $query-original)
return $m`, I still get the same 3 results.. what does that mean, range index not been created ? `<id>` is in the document properties

Comment: when I do this `let $m := cts:values((cts:element-reference(xs:QName('meta:id'))),(),
              ('map','properties'), $query-original)
return $m`, I still get the same 3 results.. what does that mean, range index not been created ? `<id>` is in the document properties.. But when I take out the `$query-original` from my above `cts:values`, it does return all my document id's, so I think the range-index is created

Comment: Following is what I noticed, when using $query (in my case $query-original) into cts:values or cts:value-co-occurrences, the search is not looking into document-properties of search fragments instead looking at the content of documents.. how do I tell to look at the document properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like `search:search` is looking at document fragments only, and your `cts:values` and `cts:value-co-occurrences` calls both are looking at properties fragments only.

If `$query(-original)` is meant to run against document fragments, wrap it in a `cts:document-fragment-query`. If you want it to run against properties fragments, then wrap it in a `cts:properties-fragment-query` (just to be sure).

Since you are using `search:parse`, you can also configure that to run against a particular `fragment-scope`. You can specify that option on top level in the options, but also inside constraints.

HTH!

Comment: Yup once I wrapped my query-original to cts:document-fragment-query.. everything worked.. Thank you very much..  
Is cts:document-fragment-query a sublcass of cts:query ? if so where is it documented..